# Creation Date PDF Google Drive

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I want to change the creation date on a Google Drive PDF file. So, how can I achieve this?

```
public static File SetLastModified(string fileID, DateTime lastModified)
{
    File file = DriveService.Files.Get(fileID).Fetch();
    file.ModifiedDate = lastModified.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'");
    try
    {
        FilesResource.UpdateRequest request = DriveService.Files.Update(file, fileID);
        request.SetModifiedDate = true;
        file = request.Fetch();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the creation date of a file using [Files:update()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update?hl=en) method

If you will check the [request body](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update?hl=en#request-body) for [Files:update()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update?hl=en) , you can only modify the parameters listed in the table provided in the document. `createdTime` property is not included in the list.

[image]

The one being modified in your sample code is the `modifiedTime` property which is included in the list of editable properties.

---

If you want to have a file with a specified `createdTime`, you need to create a new file using [Files:create()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create?hl=en). `createdTime` can be modified as part of the [request body](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create?hl=en#request-body)

[image]

---

**Additional Reference:**

[Drive API Quickstart - Setup Drive API for different platforms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js?hl=en)

[Drive API - How to create Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/create-file?hl=en)

Comment: I don't know how to do half the stuff you just explained. I went into the Files: create and I don't know what to do from here? Do I upload it somewhere and it will tell me all the info I need or what do I do from there?

Comment: Could you do an example video of you creating a file? That would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7YH6rdR-tk) is a useful video tutorial that i found using python, take note to use **Drive API v3** and include `'createdTime': '<time prefered in RFC 3339 date-time format>'` in your `metadata` [RFC 3339 date-time format examples](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#page-10).

Comment: What you need to do, download the file that you want to change the created time, and  upload the file using Drive API v3 in python with the specified `createdTime` using [Files.create()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/create-file) . You can delete the original file if you want before uploading a new one (but make sure that your code is already working before doing that). You can refer to [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python?hl=en) to learn on how to setup and access Drive API using python, which was also discussed in the video

Comment: I cannot provide you an actual on-the-spot video tutorial since I have limited resources when it comes to platform environments. I can only give you some guides and provide some references. You can look for other tutorials online just look for uploading files using Drive API with your preferred programming language.